# Drawstring with opacity on transparent image

Tags: .net, vb.net, gdi+

I want to draw a red string on a transparent bitmap with opacity, then draw this bitmap on another bitmap(or form).

The code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim Img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(300, 300)
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
        With G
            .DrawString("SIMPLE TEST!", New Font("Arial", 50), New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 0, 0)), New Point(0, 0))
            .Dispose()
        End With
        G = e.Graphics()
        G.DrawImage(Img, New Point(0, 0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The result:

[image: result]

It shows the string doesn't have opacity but have a black-red mixed color.

How should I do to draw a string with opacity on a transparent bitmap?

Comment: Set the background color of the form to white. Your text should render pinkish then. I believe that the darker current color is due to the combination of red with 50% opacity and the gray background

Comment: @EmilioLucasCeroleni I change the background color to blue. But the string color is not changed.

Comment: Call `.Clear(Color.Blue)` before drawing the string.

Comment: @dr.null I use this bitmap as a layer. I need to draw multiple bitmap on form. Use clear will cover bitmap before this bitmap.

Comment: ah, OK. Draw all the layers on a _result_ Bitmap and draw it on the Form. Merge the layers.